# event not fire on jquery click event

Tags: jquery

event not fire on jquery click event now what should i want to do to call the on click event fire.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-change

`change` - Fired when the user selects a table row or cell in the grid.

I guess you need `save` event - Fired when a data item is saved (http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-save).

Comment: when use change value of dropdown that time i need to filled the value into collection field that depend on dropdown. so this link not helpfull for me

Comment: @sangeet first link describes change event, which is used for selection, but you need save event. I have added also link for it.

Answer (score 0):

As per you code and screen Short i thought you need to alert on dropdown change.
if i am correct then please try to alert on dropdown change event.

Hope this helps you.....